# Alamofire 4 request to open weather

Tags: swift, request, alamofire

Working on my first Alamofire request and a code that is updated to Alamofire 4 . Can't get this Alamofire.request .responseJSON properly updated. I am looking at the Migration [documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#breaking-api-changes):  but not clever enough. Any suggestions how it should look?

```
    let APIKey = "myAPIkey"

func retrieveCurrentWeatherAtLat(lat: CLLocationDegrees, lon: CLLocationDegrees,
                                 block: (_ weatherCondition: WeatherCondition) -> Void) {
    let url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=\(APIKey)"
    let params = ["lat": lat, "lon": lon]

    //  Send the request
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params)
        .responseJSON { request, response, result in
            switch result {
            case .Success(let json):
                let json = JSON(json)
                block(weatherCondition: self.createWeatherConditionFronJson(json))
            case .Failure(_, let error):
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe can help you

```
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in

        switch response.result {
       case .Success(let json):
            let json = JSON(json)
            block(weatherCondition: self.createWeatherConditionFronJson(json))
        case .Failure(_, let error):
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great looks better. Ill go and test if receiving THANKS @fidetro :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let APIKey = "YourApiKeyComesHere"

//  Sending the request to Open Weather
func retrieveCurrentWeatherAtLat(lat: CLLocationDegrees, lon: CLLocationDegrees,
                                 block: @escaping (_ weatherCondition: WeatherCondition) -> Void) {
    let url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=\(APIKey)"
    let params = ["lat": lat, "lon": lon]
    print("Sending request... \(url)")
    let request = Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString)).responseJSON { (response) in
        print("Got response from server: \(response)")
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let json):
            let json = JSON(json)
            block(self.createWeatherConditionFronJson(json: json))
            print("Success: \(json)") //test
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    request.resume()
}
```

Comment: 3 small changes: .succes / .failure / block: @escaping

Comment: Tested and now it fetches a request with latitude and longitude as parameters.